# Retrieving data in android from mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-maps

I have an android app which will send location information(lat and lon values) to mysql database using php script.

Following is my php script:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username=""; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="test"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="map"; // Table name 

    $message=$_POST['a'];
    $message1=$_POST['b'];

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $query = "INSERT INTO map(id,longitude,latitude)VALUES(DEFAULT,'".$_REQUEST['message']."', '".$_REQUEST['message1']."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));
    mysql_close();
?>
```

MySQL database has the following fileds,

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | latitude | longitude |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

These things works fine.

My question is "I need to retrieve the table values from MYSQL(lat and lon values) using android app.

And from those lat and lon values I need to draw a map using android map to trace the location which I travelled.

Storing values in database works fine. I need help/idea to retrieve data from database and draw map using that in android.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea to read the data from MYSQL through Android. Please use webservices for this. You can use Resful webservice with JSON data (webservice in php and the JSON will be consumed in Android).

Answer (score 1):

Hey why don't you write Webservice to read from the MySQL DB. You can use [PHP for writing webservice](http://www.phpzag.com/web-service-using-php-mysql-xml-and-json/).

And can use [kSOAP library](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) to consume the JSON webservice. Use [this guide](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) if you are unable to get started with the library.

Good luck.